# error: column "admin" does not exist but it does exists

Tags: node.js, postgresql, api, stored-procedures, postman

I'm using postgresql and expressjs to create api.
Motive is to return boolean and msg after hitting the api.
Where my username is admin.

below is the api

```
router.get("/", (request, response) => {
  console.log(request.body.name, request.body.password);
  dbpool
    .connect()
    .then(client => {
      client
        .query(
          `SELECT checkUsername(${request.body.name},${request.body.password});`
        )
        .then(res => {
          client.release();
          console.log("logged in");
          response.send(res.rows);
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err);
        });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log("Check" + err);
    });
});
```

Api is taking the request from the body in json format using postman.

and here is the function from database which i'm calling in api.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
FUNCTION checkUsername (
    Iusername VARCHAR,
    Iuserpassword VARCHAR
) 
RETURNS BOOLEAN
LANGUAGE sql
AS $$
SELECT EXISTS(
    SELECT *
    FROM "users"
    WHERE username=iusername 
    AND user_password=Iuserpassword
);
$$;
```

After hitting the api from postman i'm getting the error: column "admin" does not exist

Comment: The query you posted returns exact 1 boolean value. It does not have a column ADMIN in it. I **guess** what you expect is the values from the "users" table, but that is in a sub-select. Values from sub-selects can be used in outer select, but they are not returned unless in the select list on the outer select.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue is solved. I was missing the '' Quotation marks
If you look at my router query method i used template string

```
.query(
          `SELECT checkUsername(${request.body.name},${request.body.password});`
        )
```

above I'm passing params to the database function.
As every param passing we need quotation marks around them.
So the query should be like below

```
.query(
          `SELECT checkUsername('${request.body.name}','${request.body.password}');`
        )
```

just like we call a function in database.

```
SELECT "checkUsername"('param','param');
```

we have to mimic the exact in our query method.